# CSS: How can i manage overflow during css scale transform?

Tags: css, overflow, transform, scale

i got an issue with overflow on scale transition.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/rukawaz/pen/XWdByLP

When i hover on left div everything is ok, transitions work smooth and there's no overflow.

```css
.header {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 85%, 0 100%);
}

.header__section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid trasparent;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.header__section::before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #034ea2;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.header__section:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}

.header__section:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.header__left {
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/26/07/45/valais-3562988_960_720.jpg);
}

.header__right {
  left: 50%;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/26/17/16/daisies-5343423_960_720.jpg);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__section header__left">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="header__section header__right">
    b
  </div>
</header>
```

But when i hover on right div i've got overflow problems with the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the z-index to fix this. Decrease if for the hovered element to make sure it will be below the other.

```css
.header {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 85%, 0 100%);
}

.header__section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid trasparent;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 1; /* added */
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out, z-index 0s 0.5s;  /* added */
}

.header__section::before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #034ea2;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.header__section:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  z-index: -1; /* added */
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out, z-index 0s;  /* added */
}

.header__section:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.header__left {
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/26/07/45/valais-3562988_960_720.jpg);
}

.header__right {
  left: 50%;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/26/17/16/daisies-5343423_960_720.jpg);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__section header__left">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="header__section header__right">
    b
  </div>

</header>
```

Or apply the scale to a pseudo element:

```css
.header {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 85%, 0 100%);
}

.header__section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid trasparent;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header__section::before,
.header__section::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.header__section::after {
  background-color: #034ea2;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.header__section:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1.4);
}

.header__section:hover::after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.header__left {
  left: 0;
}

.header__left:before {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/26/07/45/valais-3562988_960_720.jpg);
}

.header__right {
  left: 50%;
}

.header__right:before {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/06/26/17/16/daisies-5343423_960_720.jpg);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__section header__left">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="header__section header__right">
    b
  </div>

</header>
```